# How to add a button in the heading next to php echo string

Tags: html, css

i am trying to add a button to the heading, but i cant figure that out. 
It now looks this way:

[image]

The button should be at the light grey part at the right side of the "name". The code i am having now is:

```
<div class="panel panel-default bg-white nopadding">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3 class="text-uppercase text-faded">
                <?php echo $info['c_name'];?>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div id="addcinfo" class="btn btn-success" name="search1">Redigera</div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

What do i am doing wrong?

The webpage is: http://109.74.0.128/~sarath/admin
username: Jonathan@inkhousemedia.se
pw: John@123

Go on "Kund" and search for saurav and you will see the error

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: Manage html and CSS

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default bg-white nopadding">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="text-uppercase text-faded" style="float: left;"><?php echo $info['c_name'];?></h3>
        <div class="input-group" style="padding: 5px 0 5px 20px">
          <div name="search1" class="btn btn-success" id="addcinfo" >Redigera</div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added. But it stills wrong and looks like some div is not closed

Comment: RJParikh - its great, but i want the button more to right

Answer (score 0):

Add button class to your heading tag

```
<h1 class="btn btn-primary">Heading</h1>
```

Comment: Hmm, where? <div class="panel-heading"> here?

Comment: Where ever you need to add button to heading.

Comment: use some styling i.e. margin, padding etc

Comment: Nothing happend when i add <button id="addcinfo" class="btn btn-active" name="search1" style="margin-right: 15px !important;">Redigera</button>

Comment: make jsfiddle then.